# how to make sbcl automatically load a core?

Tags: lisp, sbcl

I have the core saved. How do I make sbcl load it automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-core` command line argument should do it. From the man page:

```
   --core <corefilename>
      Use the specified Lisp core file instead of the default. (See the FILES section  for  the
      standard  core,  or the system documentation for SB-EXT:SAVE-LISP-AND-DIE for information
      about how to create a custom core.) Note that if the Lisp core  file  is  a  user-created
      core  file,  it  may  run  a  nonstandard  toplevel which does not recognize the standard
      toplevel options.
```

Comment: I want to  instruct sbcl to load the core from inside sbcl so I can put it inside the init file. Then I don't have to supply commandline params for sbcl.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sbcl --core your.core` to load it automatically.